# Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10 Store support with one app with barcode scanner

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, uwp, barcode-scanner

I want to make a single Windows Store app and it will be a Windows Phone app, and I want to deploy it on Store and it should support all 3 platforms for Windows Phone. i.e, Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10.

So my question is that can I just make one app on Windows Phone 8 and then some how deploy it so it is available on all 3 platforms? Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10? or is there a seperate store for Windows 8 and 8.1 ? I've been developing Windows 10 uwp apps for sometime so I know all about that but I don't know much about Windows 8 and 8.1.

Also my app will support EAN/barcode scanner for items and some http requests for some jata in JSON format. So keeping this in mind I need to know whether I need to create 3 separate apps, or 2 separate apps or just one app?

**Note:** the app only needs to support all Windows Phone devices, the desktop version or Hologram, Xbox etc are not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app, it will work on Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10.

Comment: well thankyou, can you also tell me about publishing to store? I cant seem to find a link to windows phone 8 store, where It can be published and can run on all 3 windows phone 8, 8.1 and 10

Comment: there is just one store, you submit your WP8 app and it will tell you it will work on all the phones

Comment: I can submit my windows phone silverlight app to this store? I mean on the following link.? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows

Comment: yes, you can, I have multiple WP8 Silverlight apps still in Store

Comment: are you sure that I have to create a silverlight app? I meant I thought a normal windows phone 8 app ( non-silverlight ) must also run on all windows phone devices. but I downloaded windows 8.0/8.1 tools on visual studio community 2015, and when I try to make a new project I cant find a template for windows 8.0, all templates are for 8.1, but in silverlight I can easily find 8.0 targeted templates. I am asking this because I need to add barcode scanner or EAN scanner in the app, and I cant find a proper API for silverlight app for this purpose.

Comment: Normal WP8 app is WP8 Silverlight, there no other WP8 app type. The Silverlight vs WinRT app is WP81. You need to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK

Comment: can you please tell me how can I create app packages from windows silverlight app? to publish them on the store, I right clicked on the project but there seems to be no option for store.

Comment: just build your app in Release and then find the .XAP file in the Release directory

Comment: you were really helpful thanks a lot, Ill ask you more if I have any problem regarding this.